# Swift 3 Data not conforming to NSCoding

Tags: serialization, uikit, swift3, nsuserdefaults, nsdata

I tried posting this on Apple's forums but for some reason it's been waiting for moderator approval for a day.

So I want to give my app's users the ability to change the background color, so I have a default value which can be changed, and any changes to that color will be stored as a UserDefault, so I have a computed propety which upon request either reads or writes the value stored in UserDefaults.standard like this:

```
var homeColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            guard let data = Defaults.getValue(for: .HomeColor) as? Data else {
                return #colorLiteral(red: 0.4119389951, green: 0.8247622848, blue: 0.9853010774, alpha: 1)
            }
            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? UIColor ?? #colorLiteral(red: 0.4119389951, green: 0.8247622848, blue: 0.9853010774, alpha: 1)
        }
        set {
            let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newValue)
            Defaults.set(value: data, for: .HomeColor)
        }
    }
```

BTW Defaults is an enum I created to manage UserDefaults more easily, so please don't confuse them.

I know I should convert an UIColor to Data  and back when dealing with UserDefaults so I use NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver to do that but I still get an exeption saying:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000002439c0'
```

I can't tell which object is "instance 0x60000005d250" because the inspector is empty, and the debugging info is useless because it just says that my AppDelegate is responsible for that, instead of the actual function that raises the exception. I traced the exeption "manually" using breakpoints and found out it happens whenever I call NSKeyedArchiver.archiveData(withRootObject:), I suspect then that instance 0x60000005d250 is my newValue which is a UIColor, yet the documentation says that UIColor implements NSSecureCoding, which has an encode(withCoder:) function requirement, but there is no other object that could be because that exception only happens when I call NSKeyedArchiver.archiveData(withRootObject:) and that is the only value I pass to it, if I don't do that I get a different exception (which is expectd since UIColor is not compatible with a plist) but there is no

```
"unrecognized selector sent to instance"
```

which is the puzzling part.

I also tested the archiving function itself using a value compatible with plist and no exception was raised, so I guess it is not a bug (or at least not an obvious one) caused by some internal variable of that function.

**Update**
I kept on tracking and actually found out there's nothing wrong with `NSKeyedArchiver.encodeData(withRootObject:)` it actually returns a `Data` object, the actual exception is raised when I call `UserDaults.standard.set(value:forKey:)`(which is not shown in my code directly). So that is the function sending the wrong selector. `NSKeyedArchiver.encodeData(withRootObject:)` returns swift's own `Data` instead of `NSData`. And I searched the documentation and `Data` does not conform to `NSCoding` directly and I guess it does not do so through any another protocol. If that was the case it would still be odd since `Data` is supposed to bridge directly to `NSData`, so I am not sure what is happening here.

Comment: I think you'll find the explanation in the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443976/what-does-this-swift-ipad-crash-log-mean?noredirect=1#comment72063693_42443976

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I believe I solved this some other way but anyway according to that answer I should be able to solve this problem by editing `homeColor`'s set method's to do this: `Defaults.set(value: NSMutableData(data: data), for: .HomeColor)` where `value`'s type is `NSMutableData`.