# What does this Swift iPad crash log mean?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, dylib

App runs fine on every device that qualifies for deployment target of 9.3+ *except* iPad2. The url is good. Works on every iPhone and every other iPad. The crash is on a physical iPad2 and Simulator iPad2 iOS 9.3.

```
    doc.save(to: target, for: .forCreating, completionHandler: {(success) in
        if (success) {
            print("Save succeeded")
            }
        } else {
            print("Save failed")
        }
    })
```

This is where it crashes. Get to a breakpoint at this line, and do not get to breakpoints in completion handler or either print. Again, just the one model of just iPad.

The crash log is over my head. Does it make sense to any of you? Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Edit: expanded the crash log

[image]
[image]

Comment: When you turned on Address Sanitizer or Zombie Objects (like you _should have_ before posting this question) what did you see?

Comment: Apologies for not doing what I should have, but I have no idea what Address Sanitizer or Zombie Objects are. Never heard of them before this, so didn't know to turn them on/off. Will now try to figure out what they are.

Comment: I was a bit curt, but I do want to emphasize the incredible tools that Apple has made available. A crash in `objc_retain` or `objc_release` or any similar retain/release themed call indicates memory mismanagement. Enabling Zombie Objects in the Edit Scheme...->Run->Diagnostics tab is a good place to start. Note: a zombie is Cocoa's way of saying "dangling pointer".

Comment: :) I get the incredible tools, though sometimes ya don't even know they exist till you encounter a situation the first-time. Swift's memory usage has made sense. And I get "dangling pointer" be/c I used C with MPW back in the 80's. But this call to doc.save is made from Swift, which apparently invokes objc code which I didn't write, and that's where I get lost. Turned on AS and ZO, but haven't made sense yet of what resulted. Do have plan for proceeding though (eliminating save code till nothing is left...process of elimination). Confusion is that this is JUST one model on one iOS ver.

Comment: Different hardware means different runtime timing characteristics, and every OS release introduces kernel scheduler tweaks, both of which will uncover latent bugs in a multi-threaded app.

Comment: Can you expand the stack trace to show frames 1-to-4 above `saveToURL`?  In this case, there might be some hints from whatever `UIDocument` is doing.

Comment: At risk of looking silly, how do I expand the stack trace there, @PhillipMills? Can't find option for doing so. Through tracing code and eliminating code, found that it's getting cleanly through `override internal func contents(forType typeName: String) throws -> Any`. But it's not getting to the completion handler of doc.save. Even took app data out of doc to save an essentially empty file wrapper to eliminate our data as source. Uncertain what could be happening between end of contents:forType and the completion handler...

Comment: I haven't done it in a while myself.  There are three little icons at the bottom of the debug navigator pane.  I think the one you want to disable is "Show only stack frames with debug symbols".

Comment: Thanks, @PhillipMills, never had to mess with those buttons before. Added logs to post. Seems to be happening in block copy. I'm not sure what to try next. If I'm creating legit data, and the url is legit, and the file is actually being created, what changes are even possible to change the experienced behavior? This seems to be (from my imperfect vantage point) a case where I don't control what's happening there. Any thoughts on what experiment to try next?

Comment: Here's some guessing....  It's creating a block and trying to capture some object.  That object has already been released and, so, the `retain` attempt references an invalid address.  Have you tried the Zombies suggestion?  (Are there any delegate-type objects associated with `UIDocument`?  Is the controller that calls `doc.save` still valid?)

Comment: Hours experimenting. Thanks for suggestions, @PhillipMills. Tried zombies several diff times. Nothing identified. No delegate objects. Controller that calls doc.save still valid. Here's what I have learned. UIDocument's content(forType:) is the common element. Crash happens both when creating new doc and (re)saving existing doc on iPad2/9.3x. Happens with real data and with return of Data(). Does NOT happen if I force throw an error. All contents(withType:) does is build a file wrapper and NSKeyedArchiver.archiveData, both accurate. Has worked 10000+ times on other devices w/o one error. Arg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** It's a bug in the Swift Data type. Solution: In your UIDocument `contents(forType:)` implementation, change this:

```
return data
```

to this:

```
return NSData(data:data)
```

---

**More info:** Note that merely casting `data` to NSData won't help:

```
return data as NSData
```

That doesn't get us any further because it's the bridging that's the problem. We're *already* bridging to NSData and it isn't helping. You have to create a completely new object that is not a Swift Data object.

---

**Even more info:** For future generations who come along and want to test this, the crash can be reliably reproduced as follows. Make a new Single View project, with an app delegate and a ViewController as usual. In the *ViewController.swift* file, put this:

```
import UIKit

class WhatsUpDoc: UIDocument {
    var array = [String]()
    override func load(fromContents contents: Any, ofType typeName: String?) throws {}
    override func contents(forType typeName: String) throws -> Any {
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: array)
        return data // comment out this line to avoid the crash
        return NSData(data:data)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var doc : WhatsUpDoc?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let baseURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Untitled")
        let doc = WhatsUpDoc(fileURL: baseURL)
        self.doc = doc
        self.doc!.save(to:self.doc!.fileURL, for: .forCreating)
    }
}
```

Configure your project to have a deployment target of 9.0, and make sure you've got a 9.0 simulator SDK on hand. In Window > Devices, give yourself an iPad 2 simulator. Set that simulator as the project's destination. Run, and crash. Comment out the line that says to comment it out, and don't crash.

---

**Post-analysis Q&A:**

*Wait, so what exactly _is_ the bug? You're not saying you can't write a Swift Data object to disk, are you?*

No, it's got something to do with the peculiar threaded nature of writing during a UIDocument file save. Note that we are crashing in a background thread (thread 10 or 11 in the OP's screen shots). And what we are crashing *in* is a method of `SwiftNSData`, the NSData wrapped by a Swift Data. We're trying to enumerate the data's bytes on this background thread, and we can't; presumably this isn't thread-safe on certain device types, i.e. 32-bit devices. My solution is to get Swift Data out of the picture completely.

*Okay, so it turns out this bug is known; the answer is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41163395/341994 How about that?*

Okay, but I figured it out independently in response to the current question. I didn't find out about the other question and answer until later, when it occurred to me to do a search. So I've marked the current question as a duplicate, but I'm leaving my answer for historical purposes, esp. as it gives a clear test case (which the other question does not).

By the way, I do not know why using `NSMutableData(data:)` would be better than my solution of using `NSData(data:)`, but that's what Apple says to do, so let's just take it as gospel.

Comment: Thank you, matt. I largely understand your explanation and the solution discussed by the thread you found and linked, and have verified it solves my problem, at least on Simulator. Will get it to testers next. I appreciate your assistance and that of this community.

Comment: I knew you'd like it! I still think that instead of _just_ deleting your nonanswer's content you should move that content into the original question, as it was crucial to allowing me to test, reproduce, and work around the bug. If you don't want to do it, I'll be glad to do it for you, but I don't want to make such a big modification without your permission.

Comment: I'm glad the code was helpful. Your answer reads clean in isolation. I suspect my code would just complicate the reading of the thread. All that really matters is people can quickly find the solution to the problem (and a reason, if they care), and the accepted answer provides that unambiguously. It _was_ a good brain teaser while it lasted. Cheers.